# Qt - incompatible .lib - LNK1112

Tags: qt, windows-ce, qt-creator

I would like to write an application for Windows CE. I have already followed all the relevant steps, and started to write the application with Qt Creator.

However, when I started to build the code, there was the following error message:

```
QtCored4.lib(QtCored4.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'THUMB'
```

Maybe some more details:
I downloaded the library for Windows CE and I configured Qt-Opensource-Version 4.8.3 with following parameters:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wince50standard-armv4i-msvc2008
```

All went well. Qt Creator did recognize the new version and added Windows CE as supported platform.

Now, I guess, that there will be the same problem with QtGuid4.lib. Does anybody know, where I get a compatible file?

Answer (score 0):

The import library for a DLL - the .LIB file - contains machine code stubs that are linked into your program, that call through the import table for the EXE. Therefore, they have to match the processor family that you're compiling for.

You need to obtain the .lib file for the Windows CE ARMv4I build of QtCored4.dll. Try [these instructions for building Qt for Windows CE](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_Qt_on_Windows_CE).